# What features of C++ or other OOPL's are difficult to implement using YACC, or alternatively a recursive descent parser?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

It has been said that C++ can be done with a recursive descent parser, or with an LL parser, or even with some difficulty and LALR parser, but that these tasks require hacking and kludging. OK, so what is the most OOP-like grammar that can be done each of these parser types without any major difficulty that requires kludges? What OOP features are prohibited by each of these types of parser?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is for questions related to specific problems you're having now, not for speculating on lists of potential difficulties you might run up against in some theoretical situation. You might check the FAQ at [programmers] to see if the question is appropriate to ask there; the [faq#dontask] here is clear about what's proper here.

Comment: C++ isn't hard to parse because it's Object Oriented.  It's hard to parse because it uses the same tokens as C except with totally different grammar, and you can't tell which way a token is being used unless you analyze the whole expression it appears in.  There's no "OOPL" issues with the parsing method, just ambiguity.  So, sorry to say, the whole basis for your question is wrong.

Comment: Thanks librik, it's OK for my question to be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem with C++ is that often you cannot tell if something is a declaration or statement/expression until you've reached the semicolon. It requires "infinite lookahead", which you can do with some LL approaches (usually recursive-descent). You would definitely need a hacked LALR approach. (I used to work for Frank DeRemer, the inventor of LALR; they hired me as a guy who preferred LL to help them with a hybrid approach, but I ended up switching to a Java training company with Terence Parr, the creator of PCCTS/ANTLR before we really got into it)

Most other languages really aren't that difficult to create a LALR grammar; LL can take a little more thought because it normally cannot handle left-recursive rules (ANTLR 3 now can, but there are some limitations to how you can use it if you need a precedence grammar)

Answer (score 0):

LL, SLR, LALR, LR, define successively larger classes of *grammars,* i.e. syntaxes.

A feature doesn't have to be OO to be non-LL, non-SLR, non-LALR, non-LR, ...

Conversely there are no OO features I am aware of that aren't capable of being expressed in LL, LALR, or LR grammars respectively. [Whether that has actually been done in the dozens of languages concerned is another issue.]

In short your question doesn't make sense.